# How can I pass parameters from different functions and add subtract etc to them?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In detail I have x as a parameter for random number selected in a function.

```
def Range(x):
    Range.b = random.randint(1,x)
```

Now I want to take x and pass it a shop function I have . And if they Purchase a power up I want to take the parameter of x and do

```
x//3
```

Then take the original number of x subtract the x divided by three and print it. I have no idea what to do. I’ve already searched the internet nothing useful comes up or I they are to complicated for me to understand. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
def Range(x):
    Range.b = random.randint(1,x)       
def givenrange(y):
    print('the range is 1-',y)
def shop(points):
    time.sleep(3)
    a=input('welcome to the shop, go ahead and type yes to acesses the power ups. Type no or something else to exit\n\n')
    if a == 'yes':
        s=input('Rule of Thirds: Take out a third of the numbers giving you a more precise range: Price=500 y/n')
        if s == 'y':
            points -= 500
            print('Purchase complete: you have', points,'points')   
shop(points)
```

I use Range.b and such because I access the variables outside the function.

Comment: why aren't u using return to return the values that you want to use in other functions ????

Comment: I’m not very good a python could you explain where and why I need to use return on the functions

Comment: sharing an example in the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can return the variables from within a function in order to use them somewhere else, below is an example of the same.

```
import numpy as np
def Range(x):
    b=np.random.randint(1,x)
    return b


getting_b=Range(10)
print(getting_b)
```

also you can call it from within a function if you like. e.g:

```
def calling_b():
    getting_b=Range(10)
    divide_b_by_3=getting_b/3
```